# RuntimeError: working outside of application context when learning 'Testing Flask Applications' on the flask site

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I'm new to flask testing and when I follow the procedures of [Testing Flask Application](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/) and run [The First Test](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/#the-first-test), I get the `RuntimeError: working outside of application context`. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Flask has an [Application Context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/appcontext/), and it seems like you'll need to do something like:

```
with app.app_context():
        #test code
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering. But I found that the problem is that I download the `Tutorial` code from github directly and it seems that the  `g` context used by `get_db()` in flaskr.py is the reason. I annotate `get_db()` and replace it in the needed places, then the test code just works :P